# Why is tomcat memory usage going higher until I press Perform GC with jconsole?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, jconsole

I've been struggling with a memory consumption issue, my tomcat's mem usage in task manager keeps rising on every request I make to my webapp. I have read that the mem usage in task manager does not necessarily means there is a problem, since it summarizes heap, non-heap and native memory for JVM; however I still am unsure of what exactly is needed to be done in order to decrease the heap memory consumption automatically.

I am using tomcat 7.0.62 and JRE1.8.0_51 with an hibernate3/c3p0 application over a struts2 framework.

In the past few months we have increased functionalities for the application, at first I though it was a memory leak but every time we press the "Perform GC" button in jconsole the heap memory goes down in the graphs, hence the mem usage of the tomcat process stops increasing at the pace it was before.

So far i have set the following properties:

```
-Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62
-Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.62\conf\logging.properties
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=6060
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:SurvivorRatio=128
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=0
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

Is there any configuration parameter missing that you would recommend.
In my tomcat7w console the configuration is as follows:

[image: Tomcat7w properties]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different garbage collectors that can be set when the JVM is started. By default, the gc won't consider running if there is load on the system and still free memory. Use -verbosegc if you want to see how garbage collection is behaving. You can set the maximum heap usage (-Xmx) on startup and gc will kick in more frequently.

I recommend only worrying about it if the server is running other programs and they are being memory starved. The setup you have now is providing the best tomcat performance it can with the resources available.